# Installing Torch Extension fb-caffe-exts from github

Tags: module, machine-learning, installation, torch

I am trying to install the fb-caffe-exts extension for Torch from Github [fb-caffe-exts](https://github.com/facebook/fb-caffe-exts), specifically I am trying to use torch2caffe.

I am trying to run the test.lua demo for torch2caffe, but I am getting the following error, which refers to a line in the test.lua file:

```
t2c.run(opts, module) --attempt to call field 'run' (a nil value)
```

All the tests fail, with the stack trace referring to this error. I have installed the dependencies (fb.lualib etc) and added the lua packages to my path. Fb.python and the other dependencies import without producing errors.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your question is a bit too generic IMHO. Either there is no published luarocks but there is a rockspec and you can use `luarocks make`. Otherwise it might depend on each project (i.e. see instructions). If your questions is only related to fb-caffe-exts perhaps it's better to rename it / precise it.

Comment: Thanks, that is a fair point. I have updated the question.

Comment: Have you tried the building and installing part ? What is failing ?

Comment: I have clarified the error. Thanks.

Comment: The error just tells you that requiring the lib file failed so `t2c` is now nil, probably because the lib file doesn't exist. Could you please answer Lord of dark's question? Because it appears you copied the files but didn't install it correctly so no lib files were built.